# Does a websocket based site for best possible speed combine well with SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript

I'm tasked with creating a website and doing whatever it takes for the best possible speed.
Preferably the content of the website is updated real-time (or close to real-time).
As such, I thought it'd be a good idea to load and update all content over a websocket.

But, now I wonder, is this going to impact the SEO negatively?

This question has been asked before, many times, but the most recent one I found was in 2014. Surely we've progressed since?

Otherwise,
perhaps I could build the site as such that it could fallback to a no-js version, and serve google bots this version?

Any ideas, insights, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do not worry, Google has already invented it. Try to apply Accelerated Mobile Pages – AMP   https://www.ampproject.org/ ++  https://ampbyexample.com/

Comment: Are you going to be changing the URL based on the websocket data using `pushState`?     If not, there will be no way for users to use the URL to save their state, and no way for Google to refer visitors into anything other than the start point.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yeah. As for google, I've decided to serve them a no-js version which will fall back on good old HTTP.